# Printing spooler won't work unless restarted

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing

Something goes wrong when I start Windows 7. After each reboot of the PC, I can't print. I found that I have to restart the spooler in order to launch the impression. After that, it is good.

I did not want to restart all jours.<sup>1</sup> Do you know the problem? I looked at the spooler's start, it's "automatic" and dependent services, and it does not seem to come from there. How might I fix this issue?
__________
<sup>1</sup> Editor's note: I do not want to restart all day? every day?

Comment: There should be an error in the event viewer when the spooler doesn't start.  It would be helpful to post that error log in your question.  Most likely there's something causing it to fail when it first tries to start the service (which a delayed start may work around the issue).

Comment: I have seen this happen on systems with buggy printer drivers, or lots of different manufacturer's printer drivers installed.  You might start by uninstalling any printer drivers you don't need, and checking for the latest drivers for the printers you do need.  In my case, the printer drivers were on a Windows 2003 Terminal Server.  There were many remote users with lots of different kinds of printers.  I unfortunately had to schedule a 'net start spooler' script to run every 60 seconds in order to keep the spooler running.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.  The problem is not that the spooler is not running, it is, but it needs to be restarted in order to connect to the printers.

I have some threads that suggest that the Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS folder has some files in it.  I did verify that was the case on one computer.  When I deleted the files and restarted the spooler, all documents in the print queue printed and the folder was empty.  I shut down then restarted the computer and folder remained empty and there were no issues with printing test pages.

Comment: Deleting the left-over spooler files under `%systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have the problem at startup you can try changing the Startup Type to **Automatic (Delayed Start)**. If you prefer to have the service restart after a failure you can set it up in the **Recovery** tab of the service properties window. The settings below will restart the spooler immediately after a failure.

[image: Print Spooler Properties]